# Making a Server?

Tags: server, python

Can anyone give me some advice?  I'm looking to learn how to make an independent market for selling and buying CS:GO skins for BTC.

I'm using Django and I want all BTC to be stored and processed within the server.  Are there any frameworks or places I can seek advice as to how to do this?

I'm assuming you would have the server itself act as a wallet, which can create addresses on demand (I'm assuming I can just use pycoin or one of the python/btc projects).  When users pay to those addresses, your server/wallet can pool the amounts received and use them in outgoing transactions as well?

I understand there are payment API's, but I'd rather be entirely independent (if possible), so where can I start?

Answer (score 1):

To directly use you wallet to recieve payment, I recommend two options

- https://gear.mycelium.com/. It has payment widgets etc... and you need to do less work on your server
- http://docs.electrum.org/en/latest/merchant.html . Less GUI support, you need to execute commands on your server to set this up